# Localized libre-office in Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, live-cd, localization

When I boot from Ubuntu live CD, I can choose "Marathi" language. But firefox and libreoffice User Interface is still in English. How do I translate the menu options?

---

Update:

Here is how to set the language...

System settings - Language Support - Install/ Remove Languages - select "marathi" - apply changes - drag marathi to first place in language for menus and windows - Apply System-Wide - Close

Need to log-out / log-in again so that the changes can take effect.

My question is why doesn't choosing "marathi" at the start-up screen does all this for me automatically?

Comment: close and reopen the applications... or maybe you have to logout and relogin to translate the whole system!

Comment: Your update is a second question. Create a new question for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the Language Settings in Ubuntu and install the missing language support.

After opening the settings, the system will automatically remember the language files to be installed.

---

> My question is why doesn't choosing "marathi" at the start-up screen
>   does all this for me automatically?

We are not LibreOffice developers. [Create a bug report](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/QA/BugReport). **;)**

Comment: When I choose the language at the start-up screen, it should make these required changes. Right? Question updated.

Comment: @shantanuo You change your question fundamentally . Now my answer is superfluous. Ask a new question and revert your changes.

Comment: @shantanuo Were you satisfied with my answer? Then give me an upvote (∧). If I could solve your problem, then it would be nice if you'd mark my answer (✓). http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers ;)